# How to highlight particular word of textView in android

Tags: java, android, textview, highlight

I am building an application where a user using a search feature to check a particular word exist in the database or not. In backend process, I use a like query to filter out the proper result and displayed it in list-view.

In list-view, there is a text-view where the information is displayed and that particular word is in that text-view using setSpan I highlight that particular word with a specified color like below.

```
highlightedWord.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00) , 0, highlightedWord.length(),
                        SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);



  holder.messageTxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                holder.messageTxt.setHighlightColor(Color.YELLOW);
                holder.messageTxt.setText(firstString);
                holder.messageTxt.append(highlightedWord);
                holder.messageTxt.append(secondString);
```

It works well till here.

First Problem:
Now the problem is if there is an information of 10 line or more and my text-view is set to max-Line one. So the only first line is displayed in my text-view due to this If that particular word is in below the first line it does not highlight nore displayed. I need to display that particular line in my text-view. Example if you search in any message application it arrange the word as per it.

Second Problem:
If I am using setSpan it is not case-insensitive. It does not highlight the word with capital or small when the search word is vice-versa. Like if I search test and Test is there it will not highlight that word and If now I search Test it will highlight that same word.

Answer (score 1):

I made this method recently to highlight specific parts of a string for a textview.

```
public static SpannableString colorString(int color, String text, String...wordsToColor) {
    SpannableString coloredString = new SpannableString(text);

    for(String word : wordsToColor) {
        int startColorIndex = text.indexOf(word);
        int endColorIndex = startColorIndex + word.length();
        coloredString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), startColorIndex, endColorIndex,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    return coloredString;
}
```

This method allows you to pass in a color, the full text of the string and the word of the string you want highlighted with the color. It can be used as follows.

```
textView.setText(colorString(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryLink),
            fullString, highlightedWord1, highlightedWord2));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do your own filter: find the word, take a few words in front of it and some after it (create a sub string) and put only that in your textview.
2. Search case un-sensitive with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `holder.messageTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(firstString +"<i>"+highlight+"</i>" + secondString));` Simple html formatting

Comment: It get crash on special char.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It will highlight all the text matching with your word.

```
   origString = origString.replaceAll(textToHighlight,"<font color='red'>"+textToHighlight+"</font>"); 

   Textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(origString));
```